# PLS prediction if X is centered (using f.e. R package chemometrics)

Tags: r, self-study, prediction, partial-least-squares, chemometrics

General question about predictions in PLS, using the `chemometrics` package in `R` here for an example. The standard example for `pls1_nipals` is

```
data(PAC)
res <- pls1_nipals(PAC$X,PAC$y,a=5)
```

This returns the coefficient vector `res$b`. Now lets assume the first `200` of `209` objects (rows) of `PAC$X,PAC$y` are used for calibration and the rest is used for validation.

```
res <- pls1_nipals(PAC$X[1:200,],PAC$y[1:200],a=5)
cbind(PAC$X[201:209,]%*%res$b,PAC$y[201:209])
```

leads to

```
    [,1]   [,2]
470103.8 486.81
457944.5 488.18
491483.9 495.01
487573.0 495.45
499962.8 497.66
487223.3 500.00
656960.3 501.32
661962.2 503.89
635861.9 503.91
```

The reason for the extreme difference is, that `X` and `Y` were centered. The centering of `Y` can be eliminated bei adding `mean(PAC$[1:200])` to `PAC$X[201:209,]%*%res$b`. But how to correct the centering of `X`? First I thought by using `colMeans(PAC$X[1:200,])`, but it didn't work.

```
cbind((PAC$X[201:209,]
              -matrix(rep(colMeans(PAC$X[1:200,]),9),ncol=467,nrow=9,byrow=TRUE))
              %*%res$b+mean(PAC$y[1:200]),
      PAC$y[201:209])
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Summary: I'm puzzled as well - I'd have thought your approach should work. In fact, it does work like that with `pls::plsr` models. 
I suspect you may have found a bug (in the normalization of the inner relation coefficients), and I emailed the package maintainer about it. I'll write an answer once I know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really found a bug, which was immediately fixed by the maintainer (version 1.4.1 on CRAN - available already as .tar.gz, win binaries will take a bit longer):

```
library (chemometrics)
library (pls)

train <- yarn [yarn$train,]

res <- pls1_nipals(train$NIR, train$density, a = 2)
x.centered <- scale (test$NIR, center = colMeans (train$NIR), scale = FALSE)
y.center <- mean (train$density)
y.hat <- x.centered %*% res$b + y.center
```

For comparison, set up the (kernel)PLS model using package `pls`:

```
res.pls <- plsr (density ~ NIR, data = train, ncomp = 2)
y.pls <- predict (res.pls, data = yarn [! yarn$train])
```

now we have:

```
> cbind (y.hat, y.pls, y.hat - y.pls)
              density       density
110 53.09713 53.09713  0.000000e+00
22  52.74115 52.74115 -8.526513e-14
31  34.67483 34.67483 -8.526513e-14
41  37.48693 37.48693 -7.105427e-15
51  32.26085 32.26085 -3.552714e-14
61  21.23447 21.23447 -6.394885e-14
71  22.18097 22.18097 -4.973799e-14
```

So basically the same (up to "numeric noise")